# Is this definition of a limit correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit, $l=\displaystyle \lim_{a} f$, where $f:U\to \mathbb{R} $, $\ U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, is

> For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in U$, $0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$.

If $x$ satisfies $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then this is  the same as $x$ being a member not equal to $a$ of the open interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$. Similarly, $x$ satisfying $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ is the same as $f(x)\in (l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)$. Why is it that both of these intervals are centered at $a$ and $l$ respectively, as opposed to being any intervals containing $a$ or $l$ (respectively)?

What's wrong with the definition

> For every open interval, $I_l \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, containing $l$, there exists an open interval containing $a$, $I_a \subseteq U$, and the set $\hat{I_a}=\{x\in I_a:x \neq a\}$, such that $f[\hat{I_a}]\subseteq I_l$.

Edit: From the comments the two definitions seem to be equivalent. I'm having a hard time understanding why they're the same. An explanation would be appreciated.

Edit2: The two definitions are not equivalent unless modified as per
the (brilliant) accepted answer.

Comment: Prove that one definition implies the other.

Comment: Nothing. That would work too.

Comment: Do you know any topology?

Comment: Just because we use one definition doesn't mean another wouldn't work.  I suspect the $\delta-\epsilon$ is just a little bit more intuitive and easy to work with. (It's easier to manipulate numbers and pull them out of thin are than entire intervals. At least to my intuition it is.)    Both are equivalent so both can be definitions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson No, but I wouldn't mind looking into a relevant concept from there if it would aid my understanding.

Comment: The definition you give is basically a restatement of the usual definition given  in term of open sets in a topology class.

Comment: What's "wrong" with it is that most 12th graders are willing to try to deal with absolute values and a few Greek letters, but "$f[\hat{I_a}]\subseteq I_l$" is too likely to come off as too intimidating. Good on you for realizing that they are equivalent, but math notation can be a blockage for many.

Comment: @JonathanZ Maybe, but I think most 12th graders would also struggle to understand where the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ come from in the usual definition, and why the definition is stated as it is. I personally think that it's easier to think of one interval mapping onto another as opposed to $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s.

Comment: There is actually a small issue with your second definition: the first definition implies $\lim{x\to 0}\sqrt{x} = 0$, but the second does not, because there is no open interval containing $0$ and contained in the domain of $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Another issue is that there is no reason to assume that the image of $f$ lies in $U$, so you should not ask that $I_l$ be contained in $U$, you should just ask that it be contained in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Your second point is pretty much a typo on my part, so I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two definitions are not equivalent as stated.

The reason is a bit subtle: the first definition applies to limit points $a$ that are not in the interior of $U$. The second definition only works for interior points of $U$, as if $a\in U$ but not in the interior of $U$, then there will be no open set $I_a$ with $a\in I_a\subseteq U$. With the first definition we have $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}=0$, but under the second definition there is no limit because we cannot find $I_0$ with $0\in I_0\subseteq [0,\infty)$, regardless of what $l$ and $I_l$ are.

There are two ways to fix it: we can restrict our attention to $a$ an interior point of $U$, in which case the two are equivalent; or we can remove the requirement that $I_a\subseteq U$ and instead define $\widehat{I_a} = \{x\in I_a\mid x\in U\text{ and }x\neq a\}$.

If we do either of those, then the two are equivalent.

1. *The second definition implies the first definition.* (This does not require $a$ to be an interior point of $U$)

Assume the second definition is satisfied, and let $\epsilon\gt 0$. Letting $I_l=(l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)$, the second definition tells us that there is na open interval $I_a$ with $a\in I_a\subseteq U$, such that $f(\widehat{I_a})\subseteq I_l$.

Because $I_a$ is open and $a\in I_a$, there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subseteq I_a$. I claim this $\delta$ staisfies the first definiiton. Indeed, for all $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$, $x\neq a$, we have $x\in \widehat{I_a}$, and hence $x\in U$,  and therefore $f(a)\in f(\widehat{I_a})\subseteq I_l$. Thus, $f(x)\in (l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)$, proving that $|f(x)-l|\lt \epsilon$, as desired.

2. *If $a$ is an interior point of $U$, then the first definition implies the second definition.*

Assume the first definition is satisfied. Let $I_l$ be an open interval containing $l$. Because $I_l$ is open and contains $l$, there exists $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that $(l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)\subseteq I_l$. Since the first definition is satisfied, let $\delta_1\gt 0$ be such that $0\lt |x-a|\lt\delta_1$ implies $|f(x)-l|\lt\epsilon$. Since $a$ is in the interior of $U$, there exists $\delta_2\gt 0$ such that $(a-\delta_2,a+\delta_2)\subseteq U$. Let $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. Then $I_a=(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subseteq U$, and for all $x$, if $x\in \widehat{I_a}$ then $0<|x-a|\lt\delta\leq \delta_1$, and therefore $|f(x)-l|\lt\epsilon$. Therefore,
$$f(\widehat{I_a})\subseteq (l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)\subseteq I_l,$$
as desired.

3. *Alternatively, if we do not require $I_a\subseteq U$, and modify the definition of $\widehat{I_a}$ to be $\widehat{I_a}=\{x\in I_a\mid x\in U\text{ and }x\neq a\}$, then the two definitions are equivalent.*

To show the second definition thus modified implies the first definition, proceed as above and just note that $x\in \widehat{I_a}$ will imply $x\in U$ and $0\lt |x-a|\lt\delta$. To show the first definition implies the second definition thus modified, assume the first definition holds for $f(x)$, $a$, and $l$. Let $I_l$ be an open interval containing $l$. Since $I_l$ is open, there exists $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that $(l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)\subseteq I_l$. Then there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that for all $x\in U$, if $0<|x-a|\lt\delta$ then $|f(x)-l|\lt\epsilon$. Let $I_a=(a-\delta,a+\delta)$. Then this is an open interval containing $a$, and if $x\in \widehat{I_a}$, then $x\in U$ and $0<|x-a|\lt\delta$, hence $|f(x)-l|\lt\epsilon$; so $f(x)\in (l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)\subseteq I_l$. Thus, $f(\widehat{I_a})\subseteq I_l$, proving the second definition suitably modified is satisfied.

Note the key role of the following fact:

> $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if for every $r\in A$ there exists $\varepsilon\gt 0$ such that $(r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon)\subseteq A$.

We use this property in both directions of the equivalent, once to find a suitable "symmetric" open interval around $a$, once to find a suitable "symmetric" open interval around $l$.